# Why is my array not changing in x86 Assembly MASM

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, intel

I'm getting into Assembly and having issues with arrays. Coming from C++ background, array manipulation is relatively easy as you can do lots of magic with pointers, referencing etc. however this is not the case with Assembly. I'm doing array wrapping and wrote this program, however when I assemble this code and run it, the array does not change (I check it from Watch list). What am I doing wrong?

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096

ExitProcess PROTO,dwExitCode:dword

.data
arrayA DWORD 1001d,1002d,1003d,1004d,1005d
len DWORD 5

.code
main proc
    
    mov ebx, OFFSET arrayA
    mov edx,len
    cmp edx,1
    je lengthOne
    
    cmp edx,2
    je lengthTwo

    cmp edx,3
    jge lengthGreater

lengthOne:
    invoke ExitProcess,0

lengthTwo:
    mov eax, [ebx + 4]
    mov dx, [ebx]
    mov [ebx + 4], dx
    mov [ebx], eax
    invoke ExitProcess,0

lengthGreater:
    mov edx, [ebx + 16]                     
    push edx
    mov ecx, 16                                     
start:
    mov eax, [ebx + ecx]
    cmp eax, [ebx]
    je firstIndex

    mov edx, [ebx + ecx - 4]
    mov [arrayA + ecx], edx
    sub ecx, 3
    loop start
    invoke ExitProcess,0

firstIndex:
    pop edx
    mov [arrayA + ecx],edx
    invoke ExitProcess,0

main endp
end main
```

Comment: Should ```LengthTwo``` have ```edx``` instead ```dx```?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I debugged your code in visual studio. Your array is actually changing and it is changing nicely. There is only one problem with your code:

```
start:
    mov eax, [ebx + ecx]
    cmp eax, [ebx]
    je firstIndex

    mov edx, [ebx + ecx - 4]
    mov [arrayA + ecx], edx
    sub ecx, 3
    loop start
    invoke ExitProcess,0

firstIndex:
    pop edx
    mov [arrayA + ecx],edx
    invoke ExitProcess,0
```

If you look at this part you can see that after `loop` you are leaving the program. The problem with that is that you are not doing the `firstIndex` check after modifying the array. To fix it you can just remove the `invoke ExitProcess,0` after then loop.

```
start:
    mov eax, [ebx + ecx]
    cmp eax, [ebx]
    je firstIndex

    mov edx, [ebx + ecx - 4]
    mov [arrayA + ecx], edx
    sub ecx, 3
    loop start

firstIndex:
    pop edx
    mov [arrayA + ecx],edx
    invoke ExitProcess,0
```

So that once your loop finishes you automatically do the `firstIndex`

If you run this code you get the following array structure:

[image]

Edit:

You can maybe also do something like, but I haven't tested this one so I do not know if it works as this point:

```
start:

    mov edx, [ebx + ecx - 4]
    mov [arrayA + ecx], edx
    sub ecx, 3
    
    mov eax, [ebx + ecx]
    cmp eax, [ebx]
    je firstIndex

    loop start
    invoke ExitProcess,0

firstIndex:
    pop edx
    mov [arrayA + ecx],edx
    invoke ExitProcess,0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Ozgur. The thing is I don't want to do first index change automatically as I wanted to make sure that code only runs at a certain condition which is when the `(currentIndex-1)` is equal to the array, basically the first index in the array. I do not want to run that code until this condition is met. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Also in the watchlist I wrote arrayA only, I see you wrote something else, is this something I need to be careful about? What is the correct way to see the value of a variable/memory space in assembly? (We are learning intel x86 assembly and using MASM)

Comment: @cptalpdeniz Yes I understand that dropping automatically seems like cheating but if the other part of the code works as expected you should end with a list such as ```1001, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004```. So putting the last element to the first without checking if they are equal is okay. I will take a look at it once more when I can just to make sure that it isn't wrong.

Comment: @cptalpdeniz Also when you write ```arrayA``` you are only viewing the first element of the array. The way I did it treats ```arrayA``` as a pointer and increments the pointer to see all elements. I had to see the entire array to see it change through time. What you are doing to see the value is valid and it is the correct way

Comment: @cptalpdeniz also added an edit that would enable you to check the condition before running ```firstIndex```. You would have to try it since I cannot at the moment

Comment: These are very valuable insights and suggestions. Thank you Ozgur.

Comment: @cptalpdeniz No problem happy if I could help.